# Design pattern in RoR to use method in several objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I have the following models:

```
Shop, :belongs_to => Currency
Product, :belongs_to => Shop
Company, :belongs_to => Currency
CompanyUser, :belongs_to => Company
UserTransaction, :belongs_to => CompanyUser
```

So a shop and a company both use a certain currency.  This is the model of Currency

```
include ActionView::Helpers

class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :iso_code, :number_of_decimals, :symbol

  def to_currency(number)
    number_to_currency(number, :precision => self.number_of_decimals, :unit => self.symbol)
  end    
end
```

Ok so now when I want to display a products price I can do:

```
product.shop.currency.to_currency(product.price)
```

And if I want to display the balance of a CompanyUser I can do:

```
company_user.company.currency.to_currency(company_user.balance)
```

And if I want to display the price of a UserTransaction I need to do:

```
user_transaction.company_user.company.currency.to_currency(user_transaction.amount)
```

This all works.  But I was wondering if there exists a design pattern that I could apply which would make the to_currency available in all connected objects.  Beware, it's not just a method helper I could use since sometimes it needs to use the currency of the Shop (for example with Product) and sometimes the currency of the Company (in case of CompanyUser, UserTransaction, ...).

Ideally I would like to do: product.to_currency(product.price) or product.price.to_currency and it would look up the currency to use by checking the Shop's currency.

This example is simplified, I also have a couple of other models which have amounts that need to be converted but all those can be connected to either Shop or Company.

Comment: Including `ActionView::Helpers` in the global scope is a bad idea. You're mixing that behaviour in globally.

Comment: Have you considered putting this method into a Module and mixing it in where needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get `product.to_currency(product.price)` to work, you could do something like this

```
# common module that can be used with any object that has a currency method or attribute
module HasCurrency
  def to_currency(value)
    if respond_to?(:currency)
      currency.to_currency(value)
    else
      raise "#{class} does not have a currency"
    end
  end
end


class Product
  # mix in the module, but...
  include HasCurrency

  belongs_to :shop
  # ... product has no currency method, delegate it to the associated shop
  delegate :currency, to: :shop

  # delegate is the same as
  def currency
    shop.currency
  end
end
```

note above will not work so well for your `UserTransaction`, see z5h answer, you need methods that wrap the associations and expose `currency`

---

to implement `product.price.to_currency` you would need to monkey-patch BigDecimal (if that is the type for price), it get a little tricky; instead you might be better off with simple wrapper methods?

not re-useable, but explicit and easy to understand

```
class Product
  belongs_to :shop

  def formatted_price
    shop.currency.to_currency(price)
  end
end
```

Method invoke from symbol

```
def to_currency(method_name)
  self.public_send(method_name) if self.respond_to?(method_name)
end
```

Comment: Works great!  One thing I'm wondering.  Is there a way to rewrite @client_order.to_currency(@client_order.products_amount))
Into @client_order.to_currency(:products_amount)) where the function knows it should look for that field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-through-association) associations to relate records through related traversals. And/or something explicit like the following (but beware each object traversal will hit the DB):

```
class CompanyUser
  def currency
    company.currency
  end
end

class UserTransaction
  def currency
    company_user.currency
  end

  def to_currency
    currency.to_currency(amount)
  end
end

# ...
puts UserTransaction.find(5).to_currency
```